# Left Join not returning the missing information - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

One is for **cash** and the other is for the **stage** with the following structure

**Cash**

```
FileID     Cash   Date
1           50   03.04.2017
2           100  08.07.2015
3           70   14.09.2018
```

**Stage**

```
FileID      Stage           Date_of_stage
1           Finished       06.04.2016
1           In Process     08.07.2015
2           Complication   17.08.2018
2           In Process     14.03.2018
```

Though my tables have many more rows. So I am joining these 2 tables coz I wanna group the cash by the stage using this select:

```
select fileID,  date, cash, max(date_of_stage) as max_date
from (select c.fileID, c.date, c.cash, s.stage, s.date_of_stage  
      from cash c
      inner join stage s
      on c.fileID=s.fileID
      and s.date_of_stage < c.date
      ) x
group by fileID, date, cash
```

I only need max(date_of_stage) because it makes logically sense for our report and this isn't part of the question anyway.

The thing is: when I compare the total cash from **cash** table and the above select I get a little bit less total sum from the above select than from the **cash** table ( 7 Million from **cash** and 6.9 Milliom from the above select). Now I am trying to identify the missing records using a left join:

```
select *
from (select fileID, date, cash
  from cash) x

left join 

(select fileID,  date, cash, max(date_of_stage) as max_date
from (select c.fileID, c.date, c.cash, s.stage, s.date_of_stage  
      from cash c
      inner join stage s
      on c.fileID=s.fileID
      and s.date_of_stage < c.date
      ) 
group by fileID, date, cash ) y
on x.fileID=y.fileID
and x.date=y.date
and x.cash=y.cash
where y.fileID is null
```

But this left join doesn't give out anything so I can't identify and examine the missing records. Any tips what to do?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

try like below by chaning the left table

```
 select x.*

 (select fileID,  date, cash, max(date_of_stage) as max_date
    from (select c.fileID, c.date, c.cash, s.stage, s.date_of_stage  
          from cash c
          inner join stage s
          on c.fileID=s.fileID
          and s.date_of_stage < c.date
          ) 
    group by fileID, date, cash ) x left join 

     (select fileID, date, cash
      from cash) y    


    on x.fileID=y.fileID
    and x.date=y.date
    and x.cash=y.cash
    where y.fileID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to do the left outer join in the original query, rather than an inner join, e.g.:

```
WITH cash AS (SELECT 1 fileid, 50 cash, to_date('03/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 fileid, 100 cash, to_date('08/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 3 fileid, 70 cash, to_date('14/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual),
    stage AS (SELECT 1 fileid, 'Finished' stage, to_date('06/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_of_stage FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 1 fileid, 'In Process' stage, to_date('08/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_of_stage FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 fileid, 'Complication' stage, to_date('17/08/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_of_stage FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 fileid, 'In Process' stage, to_date('14/03/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_of_stage FROM dual)
SELECT c.fileid,
       c.dt,
       c.cash,
       MAX(s.date_of_stage) max_date
FROM   cash c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN stage s ON c.fileid = s.fileid AND s.date_of_stage < c.dt
GROUP BY c.fileid,
         c.dt,
         c.cash;

    FILEID DT                CASH MAX_DATE
---------- ----------- ---------- -----------
         1 03/04/2017          50 06/04/2016
         2 08/07/2015         100 
         3 14/09/2018          70
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strange. With the data you provided your "checking" query works fine and shows two rows. Here is the [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c801d70ac5ea1973b7dbbc096e25646).

Anyway if you need only to attach max date from second table use simple subquery:

```
select fileID,  date_, cash, 
       (select max(date_of_stage) 
          from stage s
          where fileid = c.fileid and s.date_of_stage < c.date_) as max_date
  from cash c
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=254313594a6e55321bb2dab02df478f5)</sup>**